# ejabberd doesn't store roster persistently

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm running ejabberd in Kubernetes using the following image: https://hub.docker.com/r/jprjr/ejabberd/

I've tried to test persistency by removing an account from Pidgin and adding it again. Pidgin does not load the previously added roster.

I tried Mnesia and Postgres. The Postgres database seems to be untouched by ejabberd but I don't get any erros in the logs either.

Any ideas, what could cause this behavior?

My configuration:

```
hosts: ["example.com"]
loglevel: 4
hide_sensitive_log_data: true

listen:
  - port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    access: c2s
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    zlib: true
    starttls_required: true
    starttls: true
    certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"
  - port: 5269
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    shaper: s2s_shaper
    max_stanza_size: 65536
    s2s_use_starttls: true
    s2s_certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem"
    transport: tcp

auth_method: [ldap]
ldap_servers: ["ldap.example.com"]
ldap_port: 389
ldap_rootdn: "CN=ejabberd,OU=ServiceAccounts,DC=example,DC=com"
ldap_password: "*********"
ldap_base: "OU=User,DC=example,DC=com"
ldap_uids:
  - "sAMAccountName": "%u"
ldap_filter: "(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=ejabberdUsers,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=com))"

# tried with and w/o
# default_db: odbc
# sm_db_type: odbc
# odbc_type: pgsql
# odbc_server: "db.example.com"
# odbc_password: "********"
# odbc_port: 10051

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

acl:
  admin:
    user:
      "admin1": "example.com"
      "admin2": "example.com"

access:
  local:
    local: allow
  c2s:
    blocked: deny
    all: allow
```

Comment: You do not show the whole config file. We do not see if you have roster module enabled and with which database it is configured. Please complete and clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ejabberd store roster persistently.

you need to enable mod_roster in ejabberd configuration file and database setting what you want for example

```
mod_roster:
db_type: odbc
```

it seems you are missing  configuration for more detail of configuration check these links.
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/test/ejabberd_SUITE_data/ejabberd.yml

https://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html